# ImageView' issues using adjustViewBounds

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm trying to load an images into `ImageView` which is of variable size, but as aspect ratio is maintain by "adjustViewBounds" , images with less width and more height are shown too big. I want to restrict height.

I want the image to be shown full width and variable height and also maintaining aspect ratio. As i try to resize the image by 60% of original image, it still using the same space and getting too big.

***Implementation Code:***

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_HomeFragment_PostGallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_HomeFragment_ReadMore"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

***GLide Code:***

```
Glide.with(currentFragment)
                .load(url)
                .asBitmap()
                .dontAnimate()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        Bitmap resizeBitmap = resize(resource,(int)(width * 0.4f),(int)(height * 0.4f));
                        viewHolder.ivGalleryPic.setImageBitmap(resizeBitmap);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Try `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` if its not working try different values of scale type.

Comment: @SaranSankaran Not working bro. Tried every "scaleType"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to maintain the aspect ratio

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/unnamed" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```